# How to enable more options for a DropDown Field in Silverstripe

Tags: silverstripe

I have a SilverStripe DropDown field, with CountryID:

```
DropDownField::create('CountryID', 'Country', Country::get()->map('ID', 'Name')->toArray())
```

The field is not showing the dropdown, instead it shows an input field with the ID in it and the text: "Too many related objects; fallback field in use"

How can I disable the fallback from happening.  For eg, can I set the maximum number of related objects to a higer number, say 300?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is setable like this:

```
// mysite.yml

SilverStripe\ORM\FieldType\DBForeignKey:
  dropdown_field_threshold: 300
```

Comment: Nice work solving your question and posting the answer. Did you want to mark this as the accepted answer? Thanks.